# How do I format a new line in a SASS (Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets) file?

Tags: html, css, ruby, sass

I find Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets, far more readable than Sassy CSS, however the one thing which makes it unreadable at times is that I don't know how to format a new line in the file.

For instance this rule is unreadable because it's really long.

```
.gradient
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 50% 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) -10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19) 80%, transparent)
```

It would be cool if I could do something like this, like I can in python?

```
.gradient
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 50% 0, \
                                   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) -10%,\ 
                                   rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 15%, \
                                   rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.19) 80%, \
                                transparent)
```

Is there anyway I can do this or something similar?

> If there is not a way to do this could someone point me to where I file an issue?

Comment: Seems to be in the pipeline but not here yet https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216.

Comment: Lord have mercy. And this should be fairly easy to implement as well, I might give it a try.

Comment: Also there is a question on this already but it has no accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429137/wrapping-long-media-queries-in-indented-syntax-sass.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: This might be a bit too cool, but anyway if your editor supports some kind of post-save hooks (vim does), you can write up a script that joins together lines split up with selected character(s) into a single one once you save the file. So you can have something like .scssx with your way of multi line statements, and once you save it it compiles to .scss with multi lines joined up.

Comment: I'm wondering how hard it would be to make an exception in the sass lexer for new lines. It seems trivial.